# Is there a reason why any DOMstring element doesnt get stored in a new variable to be processed further?

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I am beginner to JS,html and CSS. I am having this trouble of not being able to store a DOM string to a variable to be processed/used further in the code. const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');
I am unable to use inputs further in the code.

I have had this problem with other few excercises where I thought my code isn;t right but having checked the syntax, I am unable to figure out whats missing. Please help!

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.controls input');
const handleUpdate = function () {
  console.log(this.value);//this doesn't show any output at all.
}

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate));
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <label for="spacing">Spacing:</label>
    <input type="range" name="spacing" min="10" max="100" value="10" data-sizing="px">
  <label for="blur">Blur:</label>
    <input type="range" name="blur" value="10" min="10" max="100" data-sizing="px">
  <label for="base">Base Color:</label>
    <input type="color" name="base" value="#757B1E">
</div>
<img src="images.jpeg" alt="image">
```

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve] because your script works: https://jsbin.com/qodafagade/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @fahz I've added a Stack Snippet; change this to show the actual problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

`$('.controls input').each(function (i,value){ 
     console.log($(this).Val()); 
});`

Comment: 1. There's no jQuery in the question, 2. the script in the question already works, 3. your answer will throw an error

Comment: The script doesn't work on my system on any browser at all. Where am i going wrong on my system. I tried it online jsbin where it returns the value of when the value of blur is changing but not on my chrom, ff and IE.